# Send a REST request via HTTP

Tags: java, http, rest

So I am using an API and it says that you have to use the API via "REST" and then says "Call our service via HTTP". I've never heard of REST and was wondering if it was possible to send a REST request via HTTP and then get the response.

The API I'm trying to use is http://frengly.com/

Comment: Why don't you google what REST is? It is built over HTTP, so the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes you can. REST requests are *all* http. They're really friendly for exactly that reason - they look exactly like making an http request to a vanilla static html page.

Comment: yes, its possible you need to read up on what a rest api is and how to do http from java (hint: apache httpclient)

Comment: REST is a technology-independent architectural style (see the [original dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)) and does not necessarily have to be implemented using HTTP. However, since the REST style was in some sense reverse-engineered from the WWW, it is unsurprising that REST is normally assumed to mean HTTP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> REST stands for Representational State Transfer. (It is sometimes
>   spelled "ReST".) It relies on a stateless, client-server, cacheable
>   communications protocol -- and in virtually all cases, the HTTP
>   protocol is used.
>
> REST is an architecture style for designing networked applications.
>   The idea is that, rather than using complex mechanisms such as CORBA,
>   RPC or SOAP to connect between machines, simple HTTP is used to make
>   calls between machines.

Lear more about rest through this easy to understand tutorial: http://rest.elkstein.org/

REST basically leverage the use of HTTP methods such as GET,POST, PUT, DELETE to do the CRUD opearation on an entity.

Comment: The tutorial link really helped. Thank's alot. Will accept when I can.

Comment: Just another question, when I use this for another link, it provides the whole source. What method should I use if I want to find certain text on a page? Should I use REST to get the source and then find the text?

Comment: @user2612619 REST is not to read html contents of a web page. REST is used to do the operations of an entity in a web application. If you want to simply read contents of a web page then you should consider using some other frameworks, such as JSOUP.

Answer (score 2):

Technically REST doesn't have to be over HTTP.  But when someone says REST they usually mean it is over HTTP.  [Here's a great video explaining the definition of REST](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html).

To send a query to a http REST API using Java, you could either use the low level [URLConnection](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) or the higher level [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/).